# Check balance of individual accounts in unit tests

Tags: nearprotocol

I can't figure out how to test the balance of given accounts when writing unit tests.

For example, Bob buys something. He pays 10 NEAR. 3 NEAR should go to `alice.near`, 7 NEAR should go to `bob.near`. I want to check if the 3 and the 7 NEAR are there. I'm using VMContext. I tried switching the context, so I can use `env::account_balance()`, but that will not solve my problem.

```rust
let mut context = get_context(600_000_000_000_000_000_000_000);                                                       // Alice is person who interacts
        testing_env!(context.build());
        
        let mut contract = Contract::new_default_meta(to_valid_account("vault.near"), to_valid_account("carol.near"));       // Vault is owner, Carol will be admin
        let price = U128(500_000_000_000_000_000_000_000);
        
        contract.mint_root(test_token_metadata(), to_valid_account("carol.near"), price.clone(), None,
            Some(HashMap::from([                                                                                            // Alice: 20%
                (to_valid_account("alice.near"), 2000),                                                                     // Vault: 80%
                (to_valid_account("vault.near"), 8000)
                ]))
            );
        
        log!("caller: {:?}", env::current_account_id());
        log!("Alice balance: {:?}", env::account_balance());
        context.predecessor_account_id(to_valid_account("bob.near"));                                                       // Bob interacts with the contract
        context.signer_account_id(to_valid_account("bob.near"));
        //testing_env!(context.build());
        contract.buy_nft_from_vault("fono-root-0-0".to_string());

        context.predecessor_account_id(to_valid_account("alice.near"));                                                       // Bob interacts with the contract
        context.signer_account_id(to_valid_account("alice.near"));
        log!("caller: {:?}", env::current_account_id());
        log!("Alice balance: {:?}", env::account_balance());
```

I'm looking for a function that looks something like this: `context_get_balance("alice.near");` And it would give me the balance for `alice.near` in the simulated blockchain. Is it possible to do this somehow? Maybe it is not possible to do this. If not, what is the best approach when writing similar unit tests?

Comment: Did you ever find the answer about getting a NEAR account balance in a Rust test? See also https://stackoverflow.com/q/73171108/470749

Comment: no, i haven't find answer yet.